# Unable to send headers with websocket in Python?

Tags: python, websocket, header

This is the code in server:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, Depends, Request
import pyaudio
import random
from fastapi_jwt_auth import AuthJWT
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Settings(BaseModel):
    authjwt_secret_key:str = "1cf5449ad63af61cabb6c6ad655062ca45d53aa8e174f052802dd0df4fb75885"
    authjwt_token_expires:int = 3600

@AuthJWT.load_config
def get_config():
    return Settings()

class Credentials(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str

@app.post("/login")
async def login(credentials: Credentials, Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    if credentials.username == "user" and credentials.password == "user":
        return {"result": "success", "message": "login success", "access_token": Authorize.create_access_token(subject=credentials.username)}
    else:
        return {"result": "failed", "message": "wrong password or username", "access_token": None}

@app.get("/{username}/songs")
async def get_song_titles(username: str, Authorize: AuthJWT=Depends()):
    try :
        Authorize.jwt_required()
    except Exception as e:
        return {"result": "failed", "message": "songs: Unauthorized"}

    return {"result": "success", "message": "songs: Authorized"}


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    try:
        print(Authorize.jwt_required())
    except AuthJWTException as e:
        print(e)
        await websocket.accept()
        await websocket.send_json({"result": "failed", "message": "websockets: Unauthorized"})
        await websocket.close()
        return
```

This is the code in client:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import pyaudio
import json
import requests

access_token = None

def login():
        credentials = {
            "username": "user",
            "password": "user",
        }

        response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/login", json=credentials)

        if response.json()["result"] == "success":
            print("Login success")
            global access_token
            access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
        else:
            print("Login failed")

async def send_audio():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8000/ws"
    global access_token
    print(access_token)
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}) as websocket:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        response_data = json.loads(response)
        if response_data.get("result") == "failed":
            print(response_data.get("message"))
            return

login()
print()

response = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/user/songs", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"})
print(response.json())
print()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send_audio())
```

And this is the output when I run the client

```
Login success


{'result': 'success', 'message': 'songs: Authorized'}


eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjgzODkxNDY1LCJuYmYiOjE2ODM4OTE0NjUsImp0aSI6IjMwMGEwODY0LWRlMGYtNDdjMi1hZDZhLWYyYjdlZjRjNzkwYSIsImV4cCI6MTY4Mzg5MjM2NSwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImZyZXNoIjpmYWxzZX0.9TG1LNcZReADfIEobzpkdn9wDSDfDeI0UO5jKFryWWg
websockets: Unauthorized
```

The `@app.get("/{username}/songs")` route has the same way to authorize as the `@app.websocket("/ws")` but somehow, while the first authorized successful the seconds don't

I did a few search on google, and look like this is already the right way to send headers

```
async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}) as websocket:
```

But it didn't work for me, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you read the [FastAPI JWT Auth documentation on websockets](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/advanced-usage/websocket/)? It doesn't use headers for authorizing websockets, but a query parameter.